# Pandas Cumulative Sum in GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series data with symbol and their respective values at a particular time.

```
index,symbol,value
01:00,A,10
01:00,B,15
01:01,A,15
01:01,B,25
01:02,A,30
01:02,B,45
```

Now I want create a 4th column, which has cumulative value on time series basis for each symbol but from each cumulative row, the first row value would be subtracted for each symbol respectively

```
index,symbol,value,adjustedCumulativeSum
01:00,A,10,0
01:00,B,15,0
01:01,A,15,15
01:01,B,25,25
01:02,A,30,45
01:02,B,45,70
```

I know how to do normal cumulative sum

```
df = df.reset_index().sort_values(['index','symbol'])
df['cumlativesum'] = df.groupby('symbol')['value'].cumsum()
df = df.set_index('index')
```

But do I deduct row 0 value from all cumulative sums?

Comment: You could also use shift to just ignore the first row, something like:  `df.groupby('y')['z'].apply( lambda x: x.shift(-1).cumsum().shift(+1) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract the first value (extracted with `.iat[0]`) for each group in a `transform` function:

```
df['cumlativesum'] = df.groupby('symbol')['value'].transform(lambda g: g.cumsum()-g.iat[0])
df = df.set_index('index')

df
#      symbol   value   cumlativesum
#index          
#01:00      A      10          0
#01:00      B      15          0
#01:01      A      15         15
#01:01      B      25         25
#01:02      A      30         45
#01:02      B      45         70
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and substract first value selected by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df['adjustedCumulativeSum']=df.groupby('symbol')['value'].apply(lambda x:x.cumsum()-x.iat[0])
print (df)
   index symbol  value  adjustedCumulativeSum
0  01:00      A     10                      0
1  01:00      B     15                      0
2  01:01      A     15                     15
3  01:01      B     25                     25
4  01:02      A     30                     45
5  01:02      B     45                     70
```

Comment: apply and transform work exactly the same. What is the difference ?

Comment: It works here same, because `cumcum` return Series same size as `DataFrame` for apply and for transform. `Transform` is used if some aggregate function like `sum` is used with groupby - `apply` and `agg` return aggregate output and `transform` not. Better is see example - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44284974/2901002).

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('sy').val.apply(lambda x : x.cumsum()-x.values.tolist()[0])
Out[907]: 
0     0
1     0
2    15
3    25
4    45
5    70
Name: val, dtype: int64
```